get rid of JDialog minimize button
I have a Java 17 app and it have a few tiny javax.swing.JDialog for user input purpose, with the following create properties:
   setSize(450, 500);
   setTitle(DailyTasksApp.getResource("TasksInputDlgTitle"));
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
   setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   setResizable(false);
   setModal(true);

All of them have two button, close and minimize in its right upper corner.
I can minimize them :-) and after it, can not get back only with its parent window (JFrame).
It is normal in java?
How can I get rid of minimize button?
setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
The property nothing changed.
Best Regards:
Imre

When you create the dialog make sure you specify the parent JFrame. The dialog will be shown when the frame is shown.

setType(Type.POPUP);

Yes, dialog will be visible when JFrame come back from minimized state.
So it is normal working.
setType(Type.POPUP); make my dialog a grey rectangle :-(
